# Limit of recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac1n(x_1+2x_2+3x_3+...+nx_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was trying to solve the following limit but I just can't get it:

> Let $x_1 = a$, $a>0$, and, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_1+2x_2+3x_3+...+nx_n}{n}.$$
>   Determine :
>   $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$$

This problem tangles me more than it should. I tried finding a few terms:

$$x_1=a\qquad x_2=x_1=a\qquad x_3=\frac{x_1+2x_2}{2} = \frac{x_1+2x_1}{2}=\frac{3a}{2}$$ $$x_4=\frac{x_1+2x_2+3x_3}{3} = \frac{x_1+2x_1+3\frac{x_1+2x_1}{2}}{3}=\frac{15a}{6}$$

but I can't see any pattern emerging from that. I tried expressing each term as previous ones but that just goes on and on and I can't seem to find something reasonable that can be reduced or evaluated.

Comment: Note that $nx_{n+1}=x_1+2x_2+\cdots+(n-1)x_{n-1}+nx_{n}=(n-1)x_{n}+nx_{n}=(2n-1)x_{n}$ and conclude.

Comment: @Did Thank you Sir. I just need to think outside of this box more.. Can't believe I missed that :(